# iOS model view controller design with XML

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, ios5

I am making a tabbed bar application that has a section for Quizzes (which are written in XML). I am trying to conform to the MVC paradigm so I created a parser-delegate class, and a class for a quiz object which contains an array of questions and an array of their associated answers. My problem is that my parsing method has no way of sending it's quiz objects back to the view controller. Do I need to set up a delegate for the view controller to communicate with the Parser? Or should I just set the view controller to be the delegate for the parser and not have a separate class for the parser delegate.

Note: I am using `NSXMLParser`..

Any input as to the best way to do this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem that you UIViewController is already created when then parsing finishes, I would usually use NSNotifications for this. And then the UIViewController can wait for the NSNotification or your app delegate can and then pass it onto your ViewController. Alternatively you can use a delegate callback or a callback blocks if you are supporting iOS4+. Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the view controller is already loaded. I used the NSNotification and it worked perfectly. Thanks lots.